# How to get rid of all double commas

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

No this isn't a duplicate because all of the answers are different in other posts.

Does anyone know how to get replace something specific in a string? for example I'm trying to get rid of ALL commas that area together. Keep single commas but get rid of two only

For example:

w,h,o,,w,h,a,t,w,h,e,n,w,h,e,r,e,,t,h,e,n,,c,a,n,,b,u,t,,

I want to get rid of all instances where the double commas appear. Something kind of like:

```
var example = text.replace(/,,/g,' '); /*Space where ' ' is*/
```

If you understand what I mean. The next step is:

```
var text.replace(/,/g,'');
```

Thank you!

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function decrypt() {
        var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var x = input.split(",");
        var txtDisp="";
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if(x[i].type = "text") {
                crack = 94-(x[i]-32)+32;
                toTxt = String.fromCharCode(this, crack);
                txtDisp = txtDisp+","+toTxt;
                prep = txtDisp.replace(/,,/g,"");
            }
        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML=prep;   
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows='4' cols='100' style='resize:none;' id='input'></textarea>
<br>
<input type='button' value='execute' onclick='decrypt()' />
<p id='prompt'>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

P.s. this code is already posted somewhere else where I asked a question.

Comment: why isnt your example working? works for me to remove the double commas

Comment: Your first example works fine, doesn't it?

Comment: Wha? yeah it's not working I'll post my code.

@Hanky웃Panky

Comment: Copy paste and input this in the textarea:

61,59,44,47,43,43, ,39,54,37, ,37,47,41,44, ,59,61,48, ,53,48,42,47, ,42,54,57,53,44, ,47,56,42,57,48, ,47,56,56, ,43,61,53,58, ,47,41,44, ,42,39,61,43, ,43,53,48,59,57, ,42,54,57,44,57, ,61,48,58, ,39,47,41,50,58

@Hanky웃Panky

Comment: Did you try the code and inputting the decimal numbers in the last comment

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do:

```
var text = "61,59,44,47,43,43, ,39,54,37, ,37,47,41,44, ,59,61,48, ,53,48,42,47, ,42,54,57,53,44, ,47,56,42,57,48, ,47,56,56, ,43,61,53,58, ,47,41,44, ,42,39,61,43, ,43,53,48,59,57, ,42,54,57,44,57, ,61,48,58, ,39,47,41,50,58";
example = text.split(",,").join("").split(", ,").join("");
```

the result is:

```
"w,h,ow,h,a,t,w,h,e,n,w,h,e,r,et,h,e,nc,a,nb,u,t"
```

I myself also tried to do it like:

```
example = text.replace(/,,/g,'').replace(/, ,/g,'');
```

the result was:

```
"w,h,ow,h,a,t,w,h,e,n,w,h,e,r,et,h,e,nc,a,nb,u,t"
```

I changed your code like this:

```
function decrypt() {
    var val = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var x = val.split(",");
    var txtDisp = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(x[i]))) {
            var num = parseInt(x[i]);
            crack = 94 - (num - 32) + 32;
            toTxt = String.fromCharCode(this, crack);
            txtDisp = txtDisp + "," + toTxt;
            prep = txtDisp.replace(/,,/g, "").replace(/, ,/g, "");
        }
        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = prep;
    }
}
```

and it works. check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mMtVH/1/) out.

Comment: @XRipperxMetalX: I just updated my answer, is that result what you've expected?

Comment: Yeah that's what I expected but with a space instead. That's weird why it doesn't work for me. Could you take my code above and input this:

Comment: 61,59,44,47,43,43, ,39,54,37, ,37,47,41,44, ,59,61,48, ,53,48,42,47, ,42,54,57,53,44, ,47,56,42,57,48, ,47,56,56, ,43,61,53,58, ,47,41,44, ,42,39,61,43, ,43,53,48,59,57, ,42,54,57,44,57, ,61,48,58, ,39,47,41,50,58

Comment: @XRipperxMetalX: I just found out you have ', ,' instead of ',,', check my answer out.

Comment: the code gets rid of the , , ... Try saving my code and processing it. I have no idea why this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function decrypt() {
            var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
            var x = input.split(",");
            var txtDisp = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (x[i] !== ' ') {
                    crack = 94 - (x[i] - 32) + 32;
                    toTxt = String.fromCharCode(this, crack);
                    txtDisp += "," + toTxt;
                } else {
                    txtDisp += " ";
                }
            }
               document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = txtDisp.replace(/,/g, "");
        }
```